# InPageError while installing Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a big problem. I need to install Visual Studio 2010 but I get this error:

Suite Intergration Toolkit Executable has stopped workingg
Problem Event Name: InPageError
  Error Status Code:    c0000010

I have also tried to extract the .iso and run the setup.exe. The instalation fails in this case, too.

Also, when I tried chkdsk F: /R in cmd I got: "Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected".

I would like to mention that I have recently reinstalled windows 7 on my laptop.
What drivers should I check?

How could I solve this? I really need to install Visual Studio for a project that I have to work on.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, but I don't really know why...
I only changed the boot order and I made some windows updates.
Then I run the setup and it all worked.